# Lock two Google Sheet cells to each other

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to lock two Google Sheet cells to each other?

What I need:
I have data in cells A1 , B1 ; A2 , B2 , ...

A1-B2 / A2-B2 *must* be adjacent.

I need to sometimes copy A1-B1 to different place in the same sheet, but users are copying only A1 without B1.

So if someone copies A1 (without B1) to, for example, D5, I need to automatically copy B1 to E5.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such locking is not possible. Users can always choose to copy one cell and not the other.

Alternative suggestion: combine data A1-B1 in one cell A1, separating it by a linebreak or some other character that will not appear in the data itself. Then it will be copied as a whole. When you need to use it, you can apply `split(..., char(10))` to split the contents by the linebreak, and then work with the individual pieces.